# Lista Encadeada em Linguagem C imprimir lista inversa

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Eu preciso criar uma lista que receba `n` nós e imprima esses nós normalmente e em ordem inversa, ou seja, 1,2,3 para 3,2,1. Sou novo na área de programação e seria muito grato pela ajuda. Estou usando o Dev C ++. Eu não estou conseguindo inverter os números.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

struct no       //cria uma estrutura do tipo no
{
    int num;
    struct no *prox;
    struct no *ant;
    } *node;

int main (){
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    
    void criar_lista (int n);   //mostra que foi criado uma função criar_lista
    void imprimir_lista ();     //mostra que foi criado uma função imprimir_lista
    void imprimir_lista_inverso ();
    
    int n;                      //declaração de variável n
    
    printf ("Quantidade de nós: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    criar_lista (n);            //chama a função criar_lista
    printf ("\nDados inseridos na lista: \n");
    imprimir_lista ();          //chama a função imprimir_lista
    printf ("\nDados inversos: \n");
    imprimir_lista_inverso ();
    return 0;
}

void criar_lista (int n)        //função criar lista que puxa um valor do tipo inteiro 'n'
{
    struct no *fim_no, *aux;    //declaração da estrutura no com ponteiro para fim_no e aux
    int num, i;
    node = (struct no *) malloc (sizeof (struct no));
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Erro no 'if'em criar lista !!");
    }
    else 
    {
        node -> num = num;      //estrutura node na variável num recebe o valor de num
        node -> ant = NULL;     //estrutura node na variável ant recebe o valor de NULL
        node -> prox = NULL;    //estrutura node na variável prox recebe o valor de NULL
    }
    printf ("Digite dados para nó 1: ");
        scanf (" %d", &num);
        node -> num = num;      //estrutura node na variável num recebe o valor de num
        node -> ant = aux;      //estrutura node na variável prox recebe o valor de NULL
        node -> prox = NULL;    //estrutura node na variável prox recebe o valor de NULL
        aux = node;     
    
    for (i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        fim_no = (struct no *) malloc (sizeof (struct no));
        if (fim_no == NULL)
        {
            printf ("Erro no 'for' em criar lista ");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("Digite dados para nó %d: ", i);
            scanf (" %d", &num);
            
            
            fim_no -> num = num;
            fim_no -> prox = NULL;
            aux -> prox = fim_no;
            aux = aux -> prox;
        }
    }
}

void imprimir_lista ()
{
    struct no *aux;
    int ant, prox;
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Erro no 'if' de imprimir lista");
    }
    else
    {
        aux = node;
        while (aux != NULL)
        {
            printf ("Dado = %d\n", aux -> num);
            aux = aux -> prox;
        }
    }
}

void imprimir_lista_inverso ()
{
    struct no *aux;
    int ant, prox;
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Erro no 'if' de imprimir lista");
    }
    else
    {
        aux = node;
        while (aux != NULL)
        {   
            
            printf ("Dado = %d\n", aux -> num);
            aux = aux -> prox;
        }
    }
}
```

Desde já agradeço pelo ajuda.

Comment: Como é uma lista duplamente encadeada é só percorrê-la de trás para a frente. Creio que seria muito útil você ter ponteiros tanto para o primeiro quanto para o último nó da lista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você utilizar recursividade seu código pode ficar bem mais simples.

Sugiro as seguinte alterações:

1 - no cabeçalho:

```
 void imprimir_lista_inverso (struct no*);
```

2 - na chamada:

```
imprimir_lista_inverso (node);
```

3 - no corpo da função:

```
void imprimir_lista_inverso (struct no *aux)
{
    if(aux == NULL)
        return;
    imprimir_lista_inverso(aux->prox);
    printf ("Dado = %d\n", aux -> num);
}
```

Aqui segue uma breve explicação da função recursiva: A função é chamada primeiramente com o primeiro elemento da lista, é feita a verificação se esse elemento é NULL (que indica o final da recursão). Se não for o último elemento, primeiramente a função é chamada para o elemento seguinte e só depois que retornar dessa chamada é que será impresso o dado.

Ou seja, a primeira impressão de dado só vai ocorrer depois que a recursão encerrar (quando o critério do IF for verdadeiro).

Answer (score 0):

> Alterei um pouco o exemplo original porque eu tinha postado errado e
> para mostrar a falta que faz `Lista` não ser uma estrutura completa,
> mas apenas um nó.
>
> Vou deixar um exemplo ao final com seu código e que cria de fato uma
> lista com alguns elementos e mostra na tela. Mas acho que deve incorporar o
> que estou escrevendo a seguir antes de continuar com seu programa - @arfneto

```
struct no       //cria uma estrutura do tipo no
{
    int num;
    struct no *prox;
    struct no *ant;
    } *node;
```

Escreva seu programa em torno dos dados. Sempre. E tudo fica mais simples.
Entenda que uma lista ligada **NÃO** é um nó e sempre que programar uma lista como se fosse um nó vai ter mais trabalho sem necessidade.

Imagine essa estrutura:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned        size;
    unsigned        limit;
    Node*           inicio;
    Node*           fim;

}   Lista;
```

Ao declarar algo como `Lista` já vai ter um tamanho, um limite, um ponteiro para o fim e outro para o início. E assim mesmo que tenha 25 listas no mesmo programa cada uma vai ter seus valores preservados DENTRO da estrutura. Esse é o conceito de *encapsulamento*.

#### Entenda que os protótipos devem ficar FORA de main()

E quem sabe em um arquivo de cabeçalhos --- o tal .h por exemplo --- separado. Do modo como escreveu está errado.
É legal usar comentários em seu código, mas talvez pudesse evitar esses assim óbvios:

```
void criar_lista(int n);   //mostra que foi criado uma função criar_lista
void imprimir_lista();     //mostra que foi criado uma função imprimir_lista
void imprimir_lista_inverso();
```

#### E como inverter uma lista?

É você que está criando a lista.

Você pode inserir sempre no início, sempre no fim ou em alguma ordem.

Vamos imaginar que vai inserir sempre no início:
Então ao percorrer a lista para imprimir os valores vão aparecer em ordem cronológica inversa, claro: o último inserido será o primeiro.

Quando você listar o último cara, ele estará apontando para NULL. E esse será o ponteiro para o fim da lista. Acho que já imaginou que deveria ter um ponteiro atualizado para o fim da lista, certo? E então fazer exatamente a mesma coisa que fez para listar os elementos, mas apenas mostre o último elemento, aponte para o anterior dele e continue até ele não ter um anterior e terá listado os elementos na ordem inversa, a ordem de inserção.

Essas classificações são genericamente chamadas de **LIFO** e **FIFO** na literatura, de *Last In First Out* e *First In First Out*.

#### criar_lista()

Criar lista deveria retornar o endereço de uma Lista. Evite retornar void: em geral é um desperdício e muitas vezes um erro. **Nesse caso aqui os dois. mas o que importa é o erro**: o endereço de sua nova lista vai morrer lá dentro da função.

Faça o simples e crie uma função também que insere um valor na lista e retorna o endereço dela, pelo mesmo motivo. Algo simples como

```
    Lista*    insere( int item, node lista);
```

**Não precisa de uma função para criar a lista**

#### evite criar tipos ponteiros

Isso é muito problemático e sempre vai cair na sua cabeça. No seu exemplo, qual o tipo de `node`? `struct no*`. Para que isso? Como vai saber ao ler o programa daqui um mês?

Talvez deva usar uma convenção, como mostrei no exemplo, escrevendo os tipos que define com uma inicial maiúscula, ou todas maiúsculas, ou um underline na frente, no fim, um prefixo, um sufixo, qualquer coisa mas alguma.

Entenda que só declara variáveis, então se um nó da lista é `Node` um ponteiro para ele **SEMPRE** é `Node*`, um ponteiro para um ponteiro para ele é `Node**` e por aí vai. O asterisco fala por si só em **C**. No seu exemplo `node` não. Vai ter que se lembrar **sempre** de que node é um ponteiro e isso não é bom: é ruim. Bem ruim.

#### Não leia nada do teclado

Enquanto seu programa não estiver pronto em termos de lista não leia nada do teclado. Só vai te atrasar e não será pouco. Além de dificultar a repetição de testes com os mesmos dados.
Leia sempre de arquivo. É muito mais fácil. Pode digitar arquivos no próprio IDE. Ler do teclado é um inferno e só vai te atrasar...
E ante de ler de um arquivo use constantes em seu programa e teste um pouco.

#### Um exemplo com seu código

Como te disse, acho que deve escrever melhor a estrutura lista.
Considere que não precisa de fato de uma rotina para criar a lista. E que `imprimir_lista()` deve ser a primeira rotina a rodar em seu programa. Veja essa versão de `main()`

```
int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    Node* teste = NULL;
    imprimir_lista(teste);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1)
        teste = inserir_no_inicio(i, teste);

    Node* ultimo = imprimir_lista(teste);
    Node* primeiro = imprimir_lista_inverso(ultimo);
    // so para fechar o circulo
    ultimo = imprimir_lista(primeiro);

    return 0;
}
```

Talvez concorde que é muito mais simples de ler. E testar. Já que seus dados são apenas um `int`. Chamar `imprimir_lista()` no início é um teste óbvio porque **tem** que funcionar com o ponteiro `NULL`.
Depois um `for` insere uns elementos e `imprimir_lista()` deve mostrar os mesmos

Como eu disse no início, essa não é uma boa representação de uma lista. O simples é ter uma estrutura com *metadados* para controlar a lista, como te mostrei. É muito mais fácil.

De todo modo, eu alterei as rotinas que imprimem a lista para serem mais cooperativas: você pode chamar as rotinas a partir de qualquer ponto da lista, e `imprimir_lista()` imprime até o fim e retorna o endereço do último. E `imprimir_lista_inverso()` imprime da posiçào até o começo, mas retorna o endereço do primeiro.

Assim pode chamar uma depois da outra e o círculo se completa :D

#### mostra o esperado

```
imprimir_lista()
imprimir_lista()
Dado = 10
Dado = 9
Dado = 8
Dado = 7
Dado = 6
Dado = 5
Dado = 4
Dado = 3
Dado = 2
Dado = 1
imprimir_lista_inverso()
Dado = 1
Dado = 2
Dado = 3
Dado = 4
Dado = 5
Dado = 6
Dado = 7
Dado = 8
Dado = 9
Dado = 10
imprimir_lista()
Dado = 10
Dado = 9
Dado = 8
Dado = 7
Dado = 6
Dado = 5
Dado = 4
Dado = 3
Dado = 2
Dado = 1
```

#### O programa, quase o mesmo

Rode e compare o programa. Sugiro colocar o ponteiro para o fim e fazer todas as mudanças como listei. Se tiver mais dúvidas escreva e eu completo o exemplo com algo...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

struct no
{
    int num;
    struct no* prox;
    struct no* ant;

} *node;

typedef struct no Node;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned        size;
    unsigned        limit;
    Node* inicio;
    Node* fim;

}   Lista;

Node*       criar_lista(int n);   //mostra que foi criado uma função criar_lista
Node*       imprimir_lista(Node*);
Node*       imprimir_lista_inverso(Node*);
Node*       inserir_no_inicio(int, Node*);

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    Node* teste = NULL;
    imprimir_lista(teste);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1)
        teste = inserir_no_inicio(i, teste);

    Node* ultimo = imprimir_lista(teste);
    Node* primeiro = imprimir_lista_inverso(ultimo);
    // so para fechar o circulo
    ultimo = imprimir_lista(primeiro);

    return 0;
}

Node* criar_lista(int n)        //função criar lista que puxa um valor do tipo inteiro 'n'
{
    /*
    Node* novo = (Node*) malloc ( sizeof(Node) );
    if (node == NULL) return NULL;
    node->num = num;
        node->ant = NULL;     //estrutura node na variável ant recebe o valor de NULL
        node->prox = NULL;    //estrutura node na variável prox recebe o valor de NULL
    }
    printf("Digite dados para nó 1: ");
    scanf(" %d", &num);
    node->num = num;      //estrutura node na variável num recebe o valor de num
    node->ant = aux;      //estrutura node na variável prox recebe o valor de NULL
    node->prox = NULL;    //estrutura node na variável prox recebe o valor de NULL
    aux = node;

    for (i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        fim_no = (struct no*)malloc(sizeof(struct no));
        if (fim_no == NULL)
        {
            printf("Erro no 'for' em criar lista ");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Digite dados para nó %d: ", i);
            scanf(" %d", &num);


            fim_no->num = num;
            fim_no->prox = NULL;
            aux->prox = fim_no;
            aux = aux->prox;
        }
    }
    */
    return NULL;
};


Node*       imprimir_lista(Node* L)
{
    // imprime a lista a partir de L 
    // e retorna o endereco do ultimo cara
    printf("imprimir_lista()\n");
    if (L == NULL) return NULL;
    Node* p = L;
    Node* ultimo = NULL;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("Dado = %d\n", p->num);
        ultimo = p;
        p = p->prox;
    };
    return ultimo; // retorna o total de itens
};


Node*       imprimir_lista_inverso(Node* L)
{
    // imprime a lista a partir de L, para tras, 
    // e retorna o endereco do primeiro cara
    printf("imprimir_lista_inverso()\n");
    if (L == NULL) return NULL;
    Node* p = L;
    Node* primeiro = NULL;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("Dado = %d\n", p->num);
        primeiro = p;
        p = p->ant;
    };
    return primeiro; // retorna o total de itens
}


Node* inserir_no_inicio(int n, Node* L)
{
    // a lista existe, mas pode estar vazia
    // vai inserir sempre no inicio nesse exemplo
    Node* novo = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    novo->num = n;
    novo->ant = NULL; // vai ficar no inicio
    novo->prox = L; // vai apontar para o que estava na frente
    if (L != NULL) L->ant = novo;
    return novo;
};

// fim
```

Comment: Tentei rodar esse código, mas ele dá erro no imprimir_lista (teste), sabe me dizer por que?

Comment: @RenanPereira me desculpe: eu tinha escrito usando a estrutura `Lista` como te mostrei, mas aí achei que eu devia postar um exemplo usando sua própria estrutura e esqueci de passar o parâmetro para `imprime_lista()` e por isso não rodava. Digitei direto no SO :( my bad. Agora aproveitei para mudar as rotinas de impressão para você ver como faz falta não ter os ponteiros atualizados DENTRO da estrutura. Desculpe.

Answer (score 0):

Na realidade é sobre outra listagem. Listagem ou impressão de listas sequenciais com chave e não ordenada. Se vocês puderem me dá um norte.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).